# Unable to import BatchNormalization from tensorflow.python.keras.layers

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.7

I am trying to run a project. My TensorFlow version is 2.9.2. I need to import BatchNormalization, but I cannot import it. Here is the error message: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers' has no attribute 'BatchNormalization'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yon84.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px3i8.png)

I need to import BatchNormalization from TensorFlow.

Comment: Please do not use images for error messages, but copy them into the question as text. [Why you should not use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me ->

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
```

just remove .python from your code